# not able to create dynamic rows with textbox and dropdownlist box control in vb.net

Tags: gridview, vb.net-2010

Using vb.net.crating dynamic rows with text box and dropdown list box control in gridview , but am not able to create when i click the add new row button and also the values in that rows are not saved in the back end. here i attached mycode for ur reference.

```
designing code
 -------------
 <asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width ="100%">
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Origin country">
        <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1"  runat ="server">
          <asp:ListItem ></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem >India</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Origin City">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Destination Country">
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat ="server" >
             <asp:ListItem ></asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem >India</asp:ListItem>
             </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Destination City">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox21" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <FooterTemplate>
         <%--<asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" OnClick = "ButtonAdd_click"/>--%>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk1" runat ="server" Text ="Add new Row" ></asp:LinkButton>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```

```
code
-----
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        SetInitialRow()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub SetInitialRow()
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    Dim dr As DataRow = Nothing
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("RowNumber", GetType(System.String)))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column1", GetType(System.String)))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column2", GetType(System.String)))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column3", GetType(System.String)))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("column4", GetType(System.String)))
    dr = dt.NewRow
    dr("RowNumber") = 1
    dr("Column1") = String.Empty
    dr("Column2") = String.Empty
    dr("Column3") = String.Empty
    dr("column4") = String.Empty
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    'dr = dt.NewRow();
    'Store the DataTable in ViewState
    ViewState("CurrentTable") = dt
    Gridview1.DataSource = dt
    Gridview1.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub lnk1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim sc As StringCollection = New StringCollection
    If (Not (ViewState("CurrentTable")) Is Nothing) Then
        Dim dtCurrentTable As DataTable = CType(ViewState("CurrentTable"), DataTable)
        If (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0) Then
            Dim i As Integer = 1
            Do While (i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count)
                'extract the TextBox values
                Dim box1 As DropDownList = CType(Gridview1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(1).FindControl("ddl1"), DropDownList)
                Dim box2 As TextBox = CType(Gridview1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(2).FindControl("TextBox2"), TextBox)
                Dim box3 As DropDownList = CType(Gridview1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(3).FindControl("ddl2"), DropDownList)
                Dim box4 As TextBox = CType(Gridview1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(4).FindControl("TextBox21"), TextBox)
                'get the values from the TextBoxes
                'then add it to the collections with a comma "," as the delimited values
                'sc.Add((box1.Text + ("," + (box2.Text + ("," + box3.Text)))))
                sc.Add((box1.Text + ("," + (box2.Text + ("," + box3.Text + ("," + box4.Text))))))
                rowIndex = (rowIndex + 1)
                i = (i + 1)
            Loop
            'Call the method for executing inserts
            InsertRecords(sc)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub InsertRecords(ByVal sc As StringCollection)
    Dim str As String = "server=local host; database=traveldesk; username=root; password=test123;"
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(Str)
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(String.Empty)
    Dim splitItems() As String = Nothing
    For Each item As String In sc
        Const sqlStatement As String = "INSERT INTO tbl_testing (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4) VALUES"
        If item.Contains(",") Then
            splitItems = item.Split(",".ToCharArray)
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}('{1}','{2}','{3}'); ", sqlStatement, splitItems(0), splitItems(1), splitItems(2))
        End If
    Next
    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(sb.ToString, conn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'Display a popup which indicates that the record was successfully inserted
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(Page), "Script", "alert('Records Successfuly Saved!');", True)
    Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
        Dim msg As String = "Insert Error:"
        msg = (msg + ex.Message)
        Throw New Exception(msg)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
```

Comment: when you click on the button and your button code runs.... How many rows are returned in your ViewState("CurrentTable")?

Comment: Does it contain data? or is the initial row you started out with with the dropdown lists and textboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the insert record subroutine as below....

The problem was in your stringbuilder.appendformat statement

```
'Dim str As String = "server=local host; database=traveldesk; username=root; password=test123;"
Dim conn As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(String.Empty)
Dim splitItems() As String = Nothing
Const sqlStatement As String = "INSERT INTO tbl_testing (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4) VALUES"
conn = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Workspace\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
For Each item As String In sc
  If item.Contains(",") Then
    splitItems = item.Split(",".ToCharArray)
    sb.AppendFormat("{0} ('{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}'); ", sqlStatement, splitItems(0), splitItems(1), splitItems(2), splitItems(3))
  End If
Next
Try
  conn.Open()
  Dim cmd As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
  cmd = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sb.ToString, conn)
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  'Display a popup which indicates that the record was successfully inserted
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(Page), "Script", "alert('Records Successfuly Saved!');", True)
  Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
    Dim msg As String = "Insert Error:"
    msg = (msg + ex.Message)
    Throw New Exception(msg)
  Finally
    conn.Close()
  End Try
```

I have also modified the sql-connection and sql-command parameters to make it work with the test db i created so you will have to replace your old sql-connection and sql-command parameters.

Regards,